# Copy row if specific value in same column but from many spreadsheets

Tags: excel, row, multiple-columns

I currently have 8 spreadsheets within a workbook. I wish to search all column A's from every spreadsheet for a specific term or name, let's say 'John', then produce a new spreadsheet (called 'John') containing all of those rows data within spreadsheets 1-8.
So if he had row 2,5,7 from spreadsheet 1, row 4,8,12 from spreadsheet 3, row 5 from spreadsheet 6, etc. I would have a spreadsheet with a total of 7 rows.
I would then like to repeat this for 'Dave' & 'Sally' etc. Each time creating a new spreadsheet for each individual search term.
Basically spreadsheets 1-8 are product based, then I wish to create a 'Salesperson' based spreadsheet from that data.

Comment: Another simple method would be toimport into an access database and use queries

Comment: so, what's stopping you from doing that?  *Exactly what is the problem?*

Comment: Nothing is stopping me, I will look into it now.

Comment: It was just most of the search entries I noticed had macro's as their preferred option

Comment: Dane, the only problem is I mainly use Excel on a Mac & the forward on results to windows users. Access is not supported on the Mac, thanks very much though.